# How to find the class name in the upper line of HTML using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have this HTML codes below:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<td class="Schedule-col details">
<td class="Schedule-col timeslots">
<div class="timeslots-container" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
<div class="timeslot d1422270000000 row0 col0 outside" data-time="1422270000000" style="width: 3.22581%;">
<div class="timeslot d1422356400000 row0 col1 outside" data-time="1422356400000" style="width: 3.22581%;">
<div class="timeslot d1422442800000 row0 col2 outside" data-time="1422442800000" style="width: 3.22581%;">
<div class="timeslot d1422529200000 row0 col3 outside" data-time="1422529200000" style="width: 3.22581%;">
<div class="timeslot d1422615600000 row0 col4 outside" data-time="1422615600000" style="width: 3.22581%;">
<input class="row0 col4 widget" type="text" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div class="timeslot d1422702000000 row0 col5 current" data-time="1422702000000" style="width: 3.22581%;">
<input class="row0 col5 widget" type="text" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Basically I want to find the element with `class="row0 col5 widget"`, after I find it, I want to go up one level in that HTML and find `<div class="timeslot d1422702000000 row0 col5 current"` and then check if the class value contains `current` or `outside`.

Using Webdriver I write this code and I can find the element.

```
int ColIndex=5;
int RowIndex=0; 

WebElement pointer = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".row"+RowIndex+".col1"+ColIndex+".widget")); 
String xx=pointer.getAttribute("class");
System.out.println(xx);
```

Using this code I can find the element `<input class="row0 col5 widget" type="text" autocomplete="off">` but I don't know how to go up one level and find the `<div class="timeslot d1422702000000 row0 col5 current"` and check if it contains `current` or not.

I cannot directly find `timeslot d1422702000000 row0 col5 current` because the number `d1422702000000` is generated randomly by the system. As far as I know, we cannot use `contains` in `cssSelector`.

Any suggestion please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `//div[input[@class='row0 col5 widget']]` XPath expression:

```
WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[input[@class='row0 col5 widget']]"));
String xx = div.getAttribute("class");
```

The expression would match a `div` element that has a direct `input` child with `class="row0 col5 widget"`.

There are certainly other options. For example, to continue what you've started:

```
WebElement pointer = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".row"+RowIndex+".col1"+ColIndex+".widget"));
WebElement div = pointer.findElement(by.xpath(".."));
String xx = div.getAttribute("class");
```

where `..` would go up to the direct parent.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe , The 2nd option works very well.  The 1st option somehow returns `.row0` only , not the complete value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath axes and go one level up using the parent axis.  Link:

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp

If the page uses jQuery you can also do this:

```
$(this).parent().attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an xpath expression to explicitly retrieve the element you're trying to get.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'timeslot')][contains(@class, 'row" + RowIndex + "')][contains(@class, 'col" + ColIndex + "')]"));
```

should get you what you need, without the need to rely on DOM structure, which can be pretty brittle.

And, you are correct -- contains in not supported by all browser types for CssSelector.  It is, however, supported when using Xpath.

edit:   The expression above with match to any div with a @class attribute containing "timeslot", "row0", and "col5" when RowIndex=0 and ColIndex=5.